# react js get value from object based on key name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

my return object looks like this. I would like to extract the value if code==="targetDate". Could someone please help.

[image]

Comment: this.props.notifications.data.find(element => element.code === 'targetDate')?.value;

Comment: What went wrong with what you tried? Even ignoring `find` just iterating and comparing seems like it should have worked--what didn't work?

Comment: thanks. it worked. appreciate your quick response. this.props.notifications.data.find(element => element.code === 'targetDate').value

Answer (score 2):

Use the JavaScript array `find` function:

```
const matched = this.props.notifications.data.find(item => item.value === "targetDate");
```